# Submit Form & Separate Checkbox Values with Commas

Tags: forms

```
 <form ... method="get">
 <checkbox name="category[]" value="1">
 <checkbox name="category[]" value="2">
 <checkbox name="category[]" value="3">
 ...
```

I want the final get query to look like the following, if all items are checked:
     ?category=1,2,3

If only 1 and 3 are checked:
     ?category=1,3

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript to manipulate a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="" />
```

When either checkbox is changed, update the value (i.e. "1,3" or "1,2,3") as needed.

Comment: No problem! I couldn't think of a better non-JS-dependent approach, but maybe somebody else will chime in.